# What conditions must be met for iPad/iPhone hardware accelerated animations?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, hardware-acceleration

I'm just wandering what I must do to get hardware accelerated animations ? Do I have to se doctype HTML5 or can I use HTML4.01 or something similar ? Are there any other limitations / things I must do/use?

Also, where can I find a list of css properties (animations?) that are hardware acceleratedon iOS ?

Comment: iOS uses WebKit for rendering HTML/CSS. I think all of the `-transition`s are hardware-accelerated in WebKit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opacity and translate3d are hardware accelerated, pretty much everything else isn't. This changes in iOS5

Comment: where can I see what is also accelerated in iOS5 ?